# Can xpages display data similar to fraction format?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

May I ask can xpages display data similar to fraction format?

We have to develop a web application using domino designer version 8.5.2.

One of our task is to display data in fraction format(or similar).

Please imagine the following scenario/case:

There are several groups of people, e.g. Group A, Group B, Group C and Group D

Each group has different number of people, e.g. Group A has 10 people, Group B has 30 people, Group C has 15 people and Group D has 26 people

There are several activities, e.g. Activity 1, Activity 2, Activity 1, Activity 3, Activity 4, Activity 5

We would like to know the number of people in a group joined each activity and have a statics show in percentage.

For example, the result would be look like something like this:

[image: sample]

However, we are not sure whether it is possible to do this in xpages.

We did some research and read books but we do not have any proper or relevant results at the moment yet.

Therefore I would like to seek your advice or suggestion on this issue please. Thank you very much.

Regards,

beginner

**Edit - Update**

After receive two answers, we have an idea about display 29/50. we try the following experiment and it can show 29/50.

Here is our attempt: (in computed field, the converter is xp:convertNumber. The value is javascript and the code looks like this:)

```
var num1 = "3";
var num2 = "10";
return num1  + "/" + num2;
```

The result can display 3/10 because we set the exact numbers(num1 and num2) in javascript.

But what about if num1 and num2 are dynamic number or retrieve the number from a view?

We are currently try to solve this issue.

Grateful for your advice please. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, by using number converters. For example here are some computed fields whose values are calculated as fractions, but displayed as percentages:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{javascript:return 29/30;}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertNumber type="percent"></xp:convertNumber>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:text>
<xp:br />
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2" value="#{javascript:return 12/30;}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertNumber type="percent"></xp:convertNumber>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:text>
<xp:br />
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField3" value="#{javascript:return 15/30;}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertNumber type="percent"></xp:convertNumber>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:text>
```

This will output:

```
97%
40%
50%
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do fractions like:
<sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>10</sub>
using code like this
    `<sup>1</sup>&frasl;<sub>10</sub>`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am sorry ask how to use <sup> tag? I put the code in the xpage and I have an error "The entity "frasl" was referenced, but not declared." .

Comment: I try put it as javascript and also get error. Grateful is someone let me know my mistakes please. Thank you

Comment: Try using unicode and disable escape on the computed field: `<sup>1</sup>
 <xp:text escape="false" id="computedField4" value="#{javascript:return '\u2044';}"></xp:text>
 <sub>10</sub>`

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply @BrianGleeson-IBM, it really helps me a lot! Thank you.